# React test componentWillReceiveProps using enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, material-ui, jestjs, enzyme

I'm going to test lifecycle functions including componentWillReceiveProps using enzyme.

Before anything else, my component should be wrapped [materialUi styles](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) and be connected with redux.
Otherwise, there will be bugs in render function because I use material-ui components including FlatButton.

```
const wrapper = mount(
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
         <Provider store={store}>
            <MemoryRouter>
               <MyComponent />
            </MemoryRouter>
         </Provider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>)

// absolutely fail
wrapper.find(MyComponent).setProps({ something })
expect(MyComponent.prototype.componentWillReceiveProps.calledOnce).toBe(true)
```

So the problem is that I can't use setProps() to MyComponent because enzyme doesn't allow applying non-root component.
I'm not able to test componentWillReceiveProps or other necessary parts by changing props.

How can I set/change props of MyComponent so that I can test componentWillReceiveProps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is better to test your component in isolation. The problem is that `material-ui` is passing down its props using React `context`. You can specify the context of your component this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

const wrapper = mount(
  <MyComponent />,
  {
    context: {
      muiTheme: getMuiTheme(),
    },
    childContextTypes: {
      muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    }
  }
);
```

Another thing you need to isolate your component is to remove `<Provider>`. Instead of testing your connected component try to test component itself the way it is described in `Redux` docs: [Testing Connected Components](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md#connected-components)

Shortly - export both component and connected component, then test component by passing props. Example of the component with exports:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// Use named export for unconnected component (for tests)
export class MyComponent extends Component { /* ... */ }

// Use default export for the connected component (for app)
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

You can now import the undecorated component in your test file like this:

```
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
```

And the final test could look this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

test('test component', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MyComponent />,
    {
      context: {
        muiTheme: getMuiTheme(),
      },
      childContextTypes: {
        muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      }
    }
  );

  // Test something
  const p = wrapper.find(...);
  expect(...).toEqual(...);

  // Change props
  wrapper.setProps({foo: 1});

  // test again
  expect(...).toEqual(...);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test MyComponent, you should

```
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent);
```

Other things like Provider are not part of MyComponent so shouldn't be included in the unit test for it.

Comment: If so, bugs appear in render function while testing because I rendered material-ui buttons

Comment: Then you should mock material-ui buttons because that's out of the scope of unit testing.